# sendmail relay status

Tags: linux, email, exchange, sendmail, smtp

I have a RHEL3 server with sendmail configured to relay mail to:

```
# "Smart" relay host (may be null)
DSmailrelay
```

This relay server is an exchange server not administered by me. A few days ago its IP address was changed without my knowledge so I've updated the correct ip in /etc/hosts for the mail relay entry.

Unfortunately no mail is currently going through and maillog reports:

```
Oct 26 14:32:39 fsimag sendmail[12580]: n9Q3VxPA012580: from=root, size=3685, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<~R.*.2009102614315955@*>, relay=root@localhost
Oct 26 14:32:39 fsimag sendmail[12580]: n9Q3VxPA012580: to=wodwest@*.net, delay=00:00:40, mailer=esmtp, pri=33685, dsn=4.4.3, stat=queued
Oct 26 14:36:09 fsimag sendmail[13670]: n9Q3ZTcf013670: from=root, size=5831, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<~R.medicus.2009102614352914@*>, relay=root@localhost
Oct 26 14:36:09 fsimag sendmail[13670]: n9Q3ZTcf013670: to=tsgastro@(.net, delay=00:00:40, mailer=esmtp, pri=35831, dsn=4.4.3, stat=queued
Oct 26 14:36:50 fsimag sendmail[13882]: n9Q3aAxj013882: from=root, size=5830, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<~C.medicus.2009102614361009@*>, relay=root@localhost
Oct 26 14:36:50 fsimag sendmail[13882]: n9Q3aAxj013882: to=elmwood@*.net, delay=00:00:40, mailer=esmtp, pri=35830, dsn=4.4.3, stat=queued
```

(With domains obscured)

The mailq command shows nothing, and I've also tried connecting to this new mail server via telnet and manually sending and reports as being queued but not sent.

The administrator of this machine has put it back to me saying he sees no problems, and I just want to cover everything before passing it back to him.

Is there any other tests/logs/reasons for sendmail to only report it as "stat=queued" ? I've looked in previous logs and the relay is set to root@localhost in those but none were ever set to queued.

Thanks for any help,

Andy

Answer (score 4):

Was caused by incorrect dns servers (which had their ip changed also) in /etc/resolv.conf.

Only noticed it after seeing rejection messages in roots mail. God i hate sendmail. :(

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in the /etc/resolv.conf, or in /etc/hosts, or in the DNS Server
Try nslookup domain.com, if not resolve the problem is in the DNS (firewall, dns server). In my case the problem is in the firewall rules.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your setup, you may not want to rely on your hosts file for proper host name resolution.

Check out:

```
/etc/host.conf
```

You can control if you control the order of host,bind or bind,host in terms of DNS lookups.